# Уникальность текста

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация

Должна ли быть 95-100% уникальность текста описаний товаров в интернет-магазине? Если в тексте нужно упоминать технические термины, совместимость продукта с другими устройствами, то уже уникальность падает, так как антиплагиаторы плмечают термины и названия устройств как неуникальные. И если есть несколько сайтов, на которых есть один и тот же товар, то как тут быть с описанием? Из пальца высасывать разное для каждого сайта?

Answer (score 0):

> *И если есть несколько сайтов, на которых есть один и тот же товар, то как тут быть с описанием?*

Если описание товара на веб-сайте создано производителем этого товара или же дистрибьютором, то этот текст будет уникален. Другие веб-сайты уже будут иметь не уникальное содержание, если не создадут другое уникальное содержание для товара. Но это может быть трудно, потому что посторонние создатели контента могут не знать каких-то особенностей этого товара, на которых можно создать уникальность.

При этом все копированное содержание на посторонних веб-сайтах будет конкурировать и делить сок между собой в поиске. Чем больше веб-сайтов с копированным содержанием, тем ниже может быть их поисковый рейтинг. Вероятно по этой причине Гугл довольно негативно относиться к аффилированным партнерским веб-сайтам.

Поэтому мой ответ на основной вопрос:

> *Должна ли быть 95-100% уникальность текста описаний товаров в интернет-магазине?*

Да, уникальность описания товаров должна быть. И это должно быть 100%. Если это 95%, то это уже не уникальность.

Кроме того уникальность описания товара может быть связана с **[уникальным торговым предложением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)**, что является важной частью маркетинга.

Не имея *уникального торгового предложения* и *уникального описания товара* трудно конкурировать с веб-сайтом, который это имеет. Возможна непродуктивная трата времени, усилий, денег на веб-сайт который не возвратит ваши инвестиции и тихо умрет через какое-то время.

Comment: 100% уникальности нереально добиться при указанных в вопросе условиях.